# Indexing and managing tables for queries with COUNT(DISTINCT ...)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have several large (~billion rows, ~100GB) archive tables with customer behaviour logs for analytics purposes (no warehouse yet, in progress).

Each is filled once a day from a daily logs table and contains data for a current year.

- outside of daily inserts these tables are never modified, only selected from
- daily logs come in order of `servertime` column, which could work as a primary key, however it is not used for any query except for daily insert,
- all queries are limited by ranges of `datetime` column. These two columns are similar about 90% of the time, rest of the time there can be even several days apart,
- `servertime` notes when a log bundle was sent (so they generally are sorted ascending in flat files), and `datetime` is actual log generation time and can stay in cache multiple days.

A lot of requests demand queries counting distinct values as in query below for various time ranges (from hourly to month, 3 months, last quarter, current year) which is why we keep current year all in one place, but the row counts started getting ludicrous.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(datetime as date), 
    element, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT client_id), 
    COUNT(DISTINCT session_id), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.pageviews
WHERE DATETIME >= ''
   AND DATETIME < ''
GROUP BY CAST(DATETIME as date), element
```

Other times we have to pull all logs for a given `client_id` or `session_id` over a given period.

We had some legacy indexing (non-clustered with multiple included columns, with indexes multiple times the size of the tables).

I'm trying to improve situation a bit as we wait for a warehouse, so I started doing some basic changes.

**Question 1:**

I added clustered index on `datetime` column (to help queries) and nonclustered on `servetime` (to help daily inserts). Is this correct or should it be the other way around?

**Question 2:**

If we were to split tables into, say, monthly chunks and execute queries against a VIEW with all of them as `UNION ALL` and `datetime` as clustered index, would it help if we often calculate `COUNT(distinct X)` over periods that would span multiple such tables?

Any other fixes which could help managing this in the short term?

**Test case:**
I tested the query like the above against a 3-month period with various indexing and got the following results:

- no indexes at all - ~38 minutes
- clustered index on `datetime` - ~34 minutes
- non-clustered index for `datetime` with `include` on all relevant columns - ~34 minutes as well

EDIT: Additional info:

- Recently 33% of the time `servertime` is bigger than `datetime`, `datetime` is also affected by timezone changes, it drops to 18% in summer time (GMT+2/GMT+1)
- There is a small, but not insignificant amount of logs uploaded with `datetime` much, much earlier than current timestamp, sometimes even months. This is acceptable from our reporting perspective, but might have significant impact for clustered index over `datetime` if it keeps adding new rows way back.

Comment: `servetime` isn't in your query, so that index won't help. Also, what other columns does that index `INCLUDE`?

Comment: @Larnu there used to be a nonclustered index for ``datetime`` including ``element``, ``client_id`` and ``session_id``

Comment: An `INDEX` that *"used"* to exist isn't much help now

Comment: As I posted in the test case I don't see a significant improvement in execution time, so I would like to remove it to save on its size, which is why I'm asking these questions.

Comment: feels like you might put actual dates in the table  instead of casting and  `the > ' '` type things, perhaps show the actual table create statement for more answers

Comment: Exact datetimes are required to stay in the table because we use hourly aggregates, as well as for ordering all subsequent logs within sesssion/customer  for case by case analysis, times between each step and other ad-hoc queries. Adding separate date and hour columns would further increase the size of the table and on top of that there are other users who already use existing columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a complex problem; it is probably too broad.  But it has a simple solution, partitioning on the `datetime` column, because this is the column used for querying the tables.  I just want to point out some high level issues with this.

However, the simpler column for partitioning is `servertime` -- this would allow you to just swap partitions in-and-out.  However, that is at the expense of making queries difficult.  If you know that that a `datetime` is always in a partition within, say, three days of its value, you can make this work.

Some databases limit the number of "open" partitions that you can insert into.  I don't think SQL Server has this limitation.

However, you will have another issue.  *Results can change over time.*  So, if you are calculating the number of whatevers on 2019-10-31.  Then you can get different values on 2019-11-01 and then on 2019-11-02, and so on as data trickles in.

This can be a big issue if you are using the data for something that needs to be static, such as financial reporting.  You may want to include an arbitrary limit in queries.  Something like this:

```
select *
from . . .
where partition_date = '2019-10-31' and
      abs(datediff(day, servertime, datetime)) < 7;
```

Note that I've added a pseudo-column `partition_date` just to be clear what is used for partitioning.  You could use `datetime` directly for this.

That is, data comes in within a week.  You haven't specified if `servertime` is ever bigger than `datetime`.  Note that this can be possible even if you think it is not due to time drift on computers and possibly time zone issues.

Comment: Recently 33% of the time ``servertime`` is bigger than ``datetime``, ``datetime`` is also affected by timezone changes, it drops to 18% in summer time.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that you created a clustered index for the "datetime" column. If the "servetime" column is not searched regularly then the nonclustered index is not much helping.
What you need here and may cause a significant performance improvement is **partitioning** your table. It logically splits your tables data, So you do not need to change any of the existing queries while benefit from splitting data.
Partitioning is a complex concept. You can find useful information [here](https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/04/12/table-partitioning-in-sql-server/).